# Axios/Vue - Prevent axios.all() to keep executing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-cli

In my application wile authenticating the user I call the fetchData function. If the user token become invalid, the application will run `axios.all()` and my interceptor will return a lot of errors.

How to prevent `axios.all()` of keep runing after the first error? And show only one notification to the user?

interceptors.js

```
export default (http, store, router) => {
    http.interceptors.response.use(response => response, (error) => {
        const {response} = error;

        let message = 'Ops. Algo de errado aconteceu...';

        if([401].indexOf(response.status) > -1){
            localforage.removeItem('token');

            router.push({
                name: 'login'
            });

            Vue.notify({
                group: 'panel',
                type: 'error',
                duration: 5000,
                text: response.data.message ? response.data.message : message
            });
        }

        return Promise.reject(error);
    })
}
```

auth.js

```
const actions = {
    fetchData({commit, dispatch}) {
        function getChannels() {
            return http.get('channels')
        }

        function getContacts() {
            return http.get('conversations')
        }

        function getEventActions() {
            return http.get('events/actions')
        }

        // 20 more functions calls

        axios.all([
            getChannels(),
            getContacts(),
            getEventActions()
        ]).then(axios.spread(function (channels, contacts, eventActions) {
            dispatch('channels/setChannels', channels.data, {root: true})
            dispatch('contacts/setContacts', contacts.data, {root: true})
            dispatch('events/setActions', eventActions.data, {root: true})
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31424853/) at [Wait until all ES6 promises complete, even rejected promises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424561/). You can alternatively substitute an `AsyncGenerator` and `AsyncIterator` for `.all()` see [Run multiple recursive Promises and break when requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349721/run-multiple-recursive-promises-and-break-when-requested/48349837); see also [Jquery Ajax prevent fail in a deferred sequential loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131082/jquery-ajax-prevent-fail-in-a-deferred-sequential-loop/).

Comment: `axio.all()` uses `Promise.all()`. Can you demonstrate `Promise.all()` continuing execution after first exception or rejected `Promise`? Why is `.catch()` not chained to `.then()` to handle error?

Comment: `axios.all` doesn't *execute* anything, and it cannot "stop" anything. It just builds a promise that waits for other promises. You are calling `getChannels()`, `getContacts()` and `getEventActions()` immediately, they all are already running when you get the first error from them.

Comment: Your best bet will probably be to make one request that checks whether the user token is valid, and only when that succeeds run the others. Instead of relying on the interceptor.

Comment: Hi, I can see that you reopened a bounty on this question. How is my answer not responding to your question? Do you have other requirements that my answer does not fulfill?

Comment: Try to add an `.catch()` block at the end of your `axios.all(...)` block.

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT: [@tony19's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55351224/4547701) is much better as it allows to cancel requests still pending after first error, and does not need any extra library.**

---

One solution would be to assign a unique identifier (I will use the `uuid/v4` package in this example, feel free to use something else) to all the requests you use at the same time:

```
import uuid from 'uuid/v4'

const actions = {
    fetchData({commit, dispatch}) {
        const config = {
            _uuid: uuid()
        }

        function getChannels() {
            return http.get('channels', config)
        }

        function getContacts() {
            return http.get('conversations', config)
        }

        function getEventActions() {
            return http.get('events/actions', config)
        }

        // 20 more functions calls

        axios.all([
            getChannels(),
            getContacts(),
            getEventActions()
        ]).then(axios.spread(function (channels, contacts, eventActions) {
            dispatch('channels/setChannels', channels.data, {root: true})
            dispatch('contacts/setContacts', contacts.data, {root: true})
            dispatch('events/setActions', eventActions.data, {root: true})
        }))
    }
}
```

Then, in your interceptor, you can choose to handle the error a single time using this unique identifier:

```
export default (http, store, router) => {
    // Here, you create a variable that memorize all the uuid that have
    // already been handled
    const handledErrors = {}
    http.interceptors.response.use(response => response, (error) => {
        // Here, you check if you have already handled the error
        if (error.config._uuid && handledErrors[error.config._uuid]) {
            return Promise.reject(error)
        }

        // If the request contains a uuid, you tell 
        // the handledErrors variable that you handled
        // this particular uuid
        if (error.config._uuid) {
            handledErrors[error.config._uuid] = true
        }

        // And then you continue on your normal behavior

        const {response} = error;

        let message = 'Ops. Algo de errado aconteceu...';

        if([401].indexOf(response.status) > -1){
            localforage.removeItem('token');

            router.push({
                name: 'login'
            });

            Vue.notify({
                group: 'panel',
                type: 'error',
                duration: 5000,
                text: response.data.message ? response.data.message : message
            });
        }

        return Promise.reject(error);
    })
}
```

---

*Additional note, you could simplify your `fetchData` function to this:*

```
const actions = {
    fetchData({commit, dispatch}) {
        const config = {
            _uuid: uuid()
        }

        const calls = [
            'channels',
            'conversations',
            'events/actions'
        ].map(call => http.get(call, config))

        // 20 more functions calls

        axios.all(calls).then(axios.spread(function (channels, contacts, eventActions) {
            dispatch('channels/setChannels', channels.data, {root: true})
            dispatch('contacts/setContacts', contacts.data, {root: true})
            dispatch('events/setActions', eventActions.data, {root: true})
        }))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The [upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54940907/6277151) proposes a solution that requires waiting for *all* responses to complete, a dependency on `uuid`, and some complexity in your interceptor. My solution avoids all that and addresses your goal of terminating `Promise.all()` execution.

Axios supports [request cancelation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation), so you could wrap your `GET` requests with an error handler that cancels the other pending requests immediately:

```
fetchData({ dispatch }) {
  const source = axios.CancelToken.source();

  // wrapper for GET requests
  function get(url) {
    return axios.get(url, {
        cancelToken: source.token // watch token for cancellation
      }).catch(error => {
        if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
          console.warn(`canceled ${url}, error: ${error.message}`)
        } else {
          source.cancel(error.message) // mark cancellation for all token watchers
        }
      })
  }

  function getChannels() {
    return get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1&delay=30'); // delayed 30 secs
  }
  function getContacts() {
    return get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'); // no delay
  }
  function getEventActions() {
    return get('https://httpbin.org/status/401'); // 401 - auth error
  }

  ...
}
```

In your interceptor, you'd also ignore errors from request cancellations:

```
export default (http, store, router) => {
  http.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    error => {
      if (http.isCancel(error)) {
        return Promise.reject(error)
      }

      ...

      // show notification here
    }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ny5poomrm?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fstore.js)

Comment: This one is my favorite because it only uses Axios capabilities and because as you stated in here, the upvoted answer waits for all the promises to be completed. However I can't understand how the notification at first fail in the interceptor is supposed to be called. Is it?

Comment: @Hammerbot When the cancellation token is invoked, it throws an error for all other pending requests on that token, which causes the interceptor's error handler to be called.

Comment: Ho, ok I understand. The notification shows because the first error goes through the interceptor before first cancelation. This should definitely be the validated answer. I'm editing my answer to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Axios cancel, you can use [Bluebird Promise Cancellation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html) which is simpler.

> The advantages of the new cancellation compared to the old cancellation are:
>
> - .cancel() is synchronous.
> - no setup code required to make cancellation work
> - composes with other bluebird features, like **Promise.all**

Here is a demo. I've added some logging in `axios.get(...).then(...)` to track if each call completes.

Comment out the line `promises.forEach(p => p.cancel())` to verify that without cancellation the non-erroring calls will run to completion.

```js
//for demo, check if fetch completes 
const logCompleted = (res) => console.log(`Promise completed, '${res.config.url}'`) 

function getChannels() {
  return axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1&delay=5").then(logCompleted)
}
function getContacts() {
  return axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2").then(logCompleted)
}
function getEventActions() {
  return axios.get("https://httpbin.org/status/401").then(logCompleted)
}

Promise.config({ cancellation: true }); // Bluebird config
window.Promise = Promise; // axios promises are now Bluebird flavor

const promises = [getChannels(), getContacts(), getEventActions()];
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(([channels, contacts, eventActions]) => {
    console.log('Promise.all.then', { channels, contacts, eventActions });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(`Promise.all.catch, '${err.message}'`)
    promises.forEach(p => p.cancel());
  })
  .finally(() => console.log('Promise.all.finally'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/latest/bluebird.core.min.js"></script>
```

---

### Why does it work

**Promise.all() instead of axios.all()**

Looking at this old axios issue [Remove `axios.all` and `axios.spread` #1042](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1042) can see

> Axios uses Promise.all under the hood...

and this

```js
axios.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    // Both requests are now complete
}));
```

can be replaced with this

```js
Promise.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(function ([acct, perms]) {
    // Both requests are now complete
});
```

so we can switch to working with Promises directly and still have the same functionality.

---

**Promises fail fast**

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Promise.all_fail-fast_behaviour) we see

> Promise.all is rejected if any of the elements are rejected. For example, if you pass in four promises that resolve after a timeout and one promise that rejects immediately, then Promise.all will reject immediately.

so in this pattern

```js
Promise.all(...)
.then(...)
.catch(...);
```

`.catch()` will trigger when the first promise fails (contrast to `then()` which waits until all promises complete).

---

**Composing `Promise.all` and `.cancel()`**

The pattern is pretty simple, just cancel all the promises in `.catch()` (which is called on first error).

Ref this question for details [Stop other promises when Promise.all() rejects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48763123/4716245)

---

**Substituting Bluebird in Vue store**

This is a basic implementation in Vuex.

```
yarn add bluebird
```

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
import Promise from 'bluebird';
Vue.use(Vuex);

Promise.config({ cancellation: true }); // Bluebird config
window.Promise = Promise; // axios promises are now Bluebird flavor

export default new Vuex.Store({
  actions: {
    fetchData({ dispatch }) {
      function getChannels() {
        return axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1&delay=5");
      }
      function getContacts() {
        return axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");
      }
      function getEventActions() {  // 401 - auth error
        return axios.get("https://httpbin.org/status/401");
      }

      const promises = [getChannels(), getContacts(), getEventActions()];
      Promise.all(promises)
        .then(([channels, contacts, eventActions]) => {
          dispatch("channels/setChannels", channels.data, { root: true });
          dispatch("contacts/setContacts", contacts.data, { root: true });
          dispatch("events/setActions", eventActions.data, { root: true });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          promises.forEach(p => p.cancel());
        })
    }
  }
});
```