# Design Pattern to avoid late returning promises overwriting faster ones?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm after insight into how to avoid unwanted behaviour in loading images using promises. My real-world use is quite complex (a large threejs application) so I've boiled down my issue below to an easier to explain example.

I have a gallery div which shows an image. There are a group of thumbnails which the user can click which loads the image associated with that thumbnail and once loaded shows it in the gallery div (in the real application a promise is used here as we must load the image, then once loaded create a texture from it before passing that texture back to apply to a plane).

The issue I'm having is that if the user clicks multiple thumbnails quickly they are applied to the gallery div in the order they load which could mean that a user could click a large image to load, then a small image resulting in the small image being shown but then being overwritten by the larger image (even though it wasn't the last selected due to it being larger and therefore taking longer to load).

I'm at a loss on how to solve this issue elegantly and am hoping someone might be able to offer a suggestion on how other software/programs deal with this issue. Is it as simple as having a redundancy system to see if an image is still selected once it loads and if it isn't then abort?

Comment: Simply prevent the function to load the images from being called while it is still in progress. This could be done by setting a flag at the start of the request, and then updating the flag once the request has completed.

Comment: ... that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Trying to solve this job by updating an acontextual flag is sloppy job. Assume that your promise doesn't get resolved or rejected for an indefinite duration. Throughtout this period (if it ever ends) your flag will stuck at `false` and you can not make any more requests. No..! This is not what you want. Have a look at [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39872802/4543207) on a similar topic about cancelling previous promises.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the latest data from a promise returning service called repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824408/getting-the-latest-data-from-a-promise-returning-service-called-repeatedly)

Comment: Simplest approach is to store a rolling cancellation token, thus allowing the previous promise to be cancelled before creating a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different algorithms for dealing with this issue and part of the selection process depends upon exactly what behavior you want.  Based on your description it sounds like you want an image to be shown as soon as it is loaded, but to never overwrite an image that came after it and has already been displayed.  That means that if images are requested in the order 1,2,3, but arrive in the order 2,1,3, then you will show image 2, then 3 and never show 1.

Assuming that is the desired algorithm, then a fairly simple way of doing things is to just assign each request a sequence number and just keep track of the last sequence number that you showed.  Whenever any image finishes loading, you check if it's sequence number of above the last sequence displayed.  If not, you don't show it because it's an old image that was surpassed by a newer image.  If so, then you show it and update the `lastShownSequence` number to the sequence number of this image.  This type of algorithm requires two lasting variables to keep track of the lastShownSequence number and the nextSequenceNumber to be assigned.

Here's a sample code implementation:

```
var lastShownImage = 0;
var nextSequenceNumber = 1;

// url is image url
// elem is image element in the page to replace with newly loaded image element
function loadImage(url, elem) {
    let imageSequenceNumber = nextSequenceNumber++;
    let img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        // image loaded now
        // see if we should display it or not
        if (imageSequenceNumber > lastShownImage) {
            // hide current image so there's never any flashing of two images
            elem.style.display = "none";
            // record the sequence number we are showing
            lastShownImage = imageSequenceNumber;
            // insert new image
            let parent = elem.parentNode;
            parent.insertBefore(img, elem);
            // remove previous image
            parent.removeChild(elem);
        }
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

If you don't want `lastShownImage` or `sequenceNumber` to be open scoped like this, then they can be encapsulated either in an IIFE or in an instance of a class that you create, but since I don't see how exactly you would use this from your code or see if you needed a more generalized multi-instance implementation, I didn't add any extra complication for that.